# How to check null properties in AutoMapper using .NET Core

Tags: c#, azure-functions, automapper

I have 2 classes SMSModel, SMSRequest . I created AutoMapper and initiated in Azure Function HTTP Trigger.

**Step1:**  Installed below NuGet Package.

`AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

**Step2:**

Initiated AutoMapper Profile which is from different assembly in azure function startup.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMapperProfile)));
```

**Step3:** Created 2 Classes with few properties.

```
public class SMSModel
    {
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

```
public class SMSRequest
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The 'MobileNumber' field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("MobileNumber")]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The 'UserId' field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("UserId ")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The 'Code' field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("Code ")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

**Step4:**  Mapped Request and Model classes to mapper in automapper profile class.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<SMSRequest, SMSModel>();
              // .ForMember(dest => dest.MobileNumber, act => act.Condition(src => src.MobileNumber != null ));
        }
       
    }
```

**Step5:** Injected Automapper in HTTP Trigger Function c#. Sharing partial code.

```
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public SMSHTTPTrigger(
            ILogger<SMS> logger, 
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
            this._mapper = mapper;
        }

      public async Task<IActionResult> SendSMS(
            [HttpTrigger(
            AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req)
        {
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                SMSRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SMSRequest>(requestBody);
                var smsModelData = _mapper.Map<SMSModel>(data);

               // Here I want to list all properties (fields) which are having null or empty string without checking each property manually like as below ..

               if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(smsModelData.MobileNumber)
               {
               }

        }
```

I tried `.ForMember with condition` but in vain.

Is there any possibility to check the fields with null or empty string using AutoMapper?

Comment: Hi.  I understand you question, but I cannot help wonder the relation between data validation and AutoMapper.  AutoMapper is a helper library that makes mapping of data easy between two disparate classes.  Never have I heard that AutoMapper is also a validation library.

Comment: Is your goal to exclude properties with `null` values from your mappings?

Comment: @bolkay No, Its opposite, To find out ```null``` properties.

Comment: Not sure Automapper will help you with that. You can however do this easily with `Reflection`.

Comment: @bolkay Any reference link

Comment: @bolkay I tried with some extension and posted as answer. Please check and vote.

Comment: Glad to see you've resolved it. You can see a sample [implementation here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gu7aEb) using Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to find out only Null properties. Hence used extension as an alternative and it worked for me without Automapper.

**Extension Class:**

```
public static class HttpRequestValidationExtension
    {
        public static bool IsValid(this object o, out ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults)
        {
            validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            return Validator.TryValidateObject(o, new ValidationContext(o, null, null), validationResults, true);
        }
    }
```

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
SMSRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SMSRequest>(requestBody);

if (!data.IsValid(validationResults: out var validationResults))
                {
                   //Incase if want to loop for each property 
                    foreach (var failure in validationResults)
                    {
                        string message = failure.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault() + " Message" + failure.ErrorMessage;
                        //Console.WriteLine("Property " + memberName + " failed validation. Error was: " + failure.ErrorMessage);
                    }

                   //Single line code  statement to fetch all null properties

                    string invalidrequestErrorMessage = $" Invalid Request body. Please check these errors. {string.Join(" ", validationResults.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage))}";
                    var badrequestObject = new
                    {
                        StatusCode = 400,
                        ErrorDetails = new
                        {
                            FunctionName = nameof(SendSMS),
                            ErrorMessage = invalidrequestErrorMessage
                        }
                    };
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(badrequestObject);
                }
```